# Number of bitangents to connected algebraic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schubert-calculus

[Schubert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schubert) 
showed that a plane algebraic curve of degree $d$ has
at most
$$
\tfrac{1}{2} d (d-2) (d-3) (d+2) 
=
\tfrac{1}{2}d^4-d^3-\tfrac{9}{2} d^2 +9 d
$$
bitangents (a.k.a., double tangents).
And this number of real bitangents is achievable for a quartic,
such as Trott's quartic:

---

[image: Trott28bits]

          

<sup>(Image from [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bitangent.html).)</sup>

---

(I learned this from Jan-MagnusØkland [@MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494999/237).)

I have a curve $C$ that is a subcurve of a real algebraic plane curve of degree $d$, with these restrictions:

- $C$ is connected (unlike Trott's quartic).
- $C$ is simple, i.e., non-self-intersecting, i.e., it is embedded.
- $C$ has no cusp singularities.
- $C$ is an open curve, i.e., it is not closed to a cycle.

My question is:

> ***Q***. Under these restrictions, is there a smaller upperbound
>   than provided by Schubert's formula? In particular, are there curves $C$ meeting
>   my conditions still with $\Omega( d^4 )$ bitangents? 
>   Maybe instead $O(d^3)$ holds?

Comment: For real quartics, see [Zeuthen](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002242672) cited from [Plaumann, Sturmfels, Vinzant](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717111000198) and summarised at [Vinzant's page (archived)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120129140441/http://www-personal.umich.edu/~vinzant/quartics.html).