# Teaching algebraic geometry to computer science people

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

How does one teach algebraic geometry to computer scientists/engineers?

There is a [2009 book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/algebraic-geometry-and-statistical-learning-theory/9C8FD1BDC817E2FC79117C7F41544A3A) by Sumio Watanabe.  It has its prerequisites, and would require plenty of adaptation. Is there anything better?

Ideally, it should involve geometrical representations of datasets, transformations of finite dimensional spaces, decision-making, searching subspaces/ boundaries, computation, and aspects of visualization.

Comment: You should at least provide a link to the book that you mention, and some more indication of context, such as a list of applications for which computer scientists or engineers might want to know some algebraic geometry.

Comment: Added a bit. Applications to optimization methods would additionally qualify.

Comment: Kiran Kedlaya had a course on [Weil Cohomology in practice](https://kskedlaya.org/math206a-fall19/) that had some (theoretical) computer scientists attend.

Comment: Your list of topics is a little confusing to me. You could easily fill a course on those topics without ever mentioning algebraic geometry. Is your goal really to teach algebraic geometry, as algebraic geometers understand the subject? Or is the goal to give a crash course to help students understand specific papers in these applied areas that use the language of algebraic geometry? These are very different goals, and I don't think it's realistic to try to do both.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to explain to an engineer what algebraic geometry is?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/313503)

Answer (score 4):

You might try

S. S. Abhyankar: [Algebraic geometry for scientists and engineers](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-35), Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 35. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (ISBN 0-8218-1535-0). xiii, 295 p. (1990). [ZBL0709.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0709.14001).